# Pull - Not getting the file

Tags: git, github, tortoisegit

I am using Tortoisegit.

I am doing a Pull, but I am not getting the file from the remote repository.

Below are steps I am doing:

1) Dit Git Clone
Got the repository to my local disk

2) Deleted one file manually (NOT using the delete option from Tortoise )

3) Doing 'Pull' using Tortosegit, But I am getting the file that I deleted

Tortoisegit returns with Success..

```
git.exe pull --progress -v --no-rebase "WB" master

From https://github.com/wb/WBR_01
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
= [up to date]      master     -> WB/master
Already up to date.

Success (2406 ms @ 25/08/2018 21:02:51)
```

Can anyone let me know why Pull us not getting the file from remote?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you pull, your git client will connect to the configured remote and retrieve any new commits (fetch) and then attempt to apply them to your local branch (merge).

In your case there are no new commits and hence nothing to change.

If you want to throw away your local changes and have your working area reflect the current commit, you could either use the clean or reset commands.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using revert unless you want to mess up your git commit history.

Answer (score 0):

Git pull incorporates **changes** from the remote branch into your local branch. In your case, you do not have any new commits in the remote branch.

If you use TortoiseGit and you want to get the deleted file back you need to use "**Revert**" on the parent folder (or commit or repository status dialog). Right click to pop up the context menu and then select the command TortoiseGit → Revert. A dialog will pop up showing you the files that you have deleted(or changed) and can restore(or revert). Select those you want to restore(or revert) and click on OK.

Answer (score 0):

You have to distinguish between the Git commit history and the changes in your local working directory. Both can co-exist in the same repository and need not necessarily have an effect on the other.

What you have done is deleted a file without telling Git about it. If you do `git status` it will show you:

```
changes not staged for commit:
    deleted: path/to/your/deleted/file
```

When you do a `git pull`, Git will first fetch all remote commits and then try to merge them to your local branch (either by a real merge commit, or by doing a fast-forward). From the output you have posted, there are no new commits on the remote, so nothing will happen (your file is still deleted, but you have not told Git so).

Since the gist of your question is how to get the file back into your working directory, there are two options:

1. Use `git checkout -- path/to/your/deleted/file`

   `git checkout` can be used to move to different branches, but it can also be used to check out a specific version of a file. In your case, the version at `HEAD` (the currently checked-out commit).
2. Use `git reset --hard HEAD` to wipe out **all** local changes. Careful, there is no *undo* for this operation.